# Getting the text of a paragraph element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
`<div id="businessCategory12">`
`<p style="margin-top: 0px;line-height:80%;margin-left:5px;font-weight: bold;color:#00004C">Business Types</p>`
`<p style="margin-top: 0px;line-height:80%;margin-left:15px;font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minority Owned Business</p>`
`<p style="margin-top: 0px;line-height:80%;margin-left:15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Black American Owned</p>`
`</div>``
```

I am working on a webscraping tool for a client. I need to get the text from the third paragraph above using selenium (python) but I am having a lot of trouble. The text should be "Black American Owned".  I have tried the following but it keeps giving me a null value. What am I doing wrong here?

Any help or other way to get the text would be greatly greatly appreciated!

```
`minority = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='businessCategory12']/p[3]")`
`minority_owned = minority.text`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the node is hidden try with `textContent` instead of text

```
minority = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='businessCategory12']/p[3]")
minority_owned = minority.get_attribute("textContent")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help this was exactly what I needed. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="businessCategory12">
<p style="margin-top: 0px;line-height:80%;margin-left:5px;font-weight: bold;color:#00004C">Business Types</p>
<p style="margin-top: 0px;line-height:80%;margin-left:15px;font-weight: bold;">Minority Owned Business</p>
<p style="margin-top: 0px;line-height:80%;margin-left:15px;">Black American Owned</p>
</div>
```

**Just try:
//p[3]/text()**

Here is a good site to play around xpath:
https://scrapinghub.github.io/xpath-playground/

Comment: Thanks for the help! Another fix was the trick but I really appreciate your help. :)